# Using autoupdater in Electron download-progress

Tags: auto-update

hope I detail this correctly (newbie), if not, please mention so I can learn.

I have the following function in my main.js:

```
autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
let log_message = "Download speed: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
log_message = log_message + ' - Downloaded ' + progressObj.percent + '%';
log_message = log_message + ' (' + progressObj.transferred + "/" + progressObj.total + ')';
sendStatusToWindow(log_message);
```

})

I then have the following script tag in my landingpage.html

```
<script>
        // Listen for messages
        ipcRenderer.on('info', function (event, text) {
            var container = document.getElementById('info');
            var message = document.createElement('div');
            message.innerHTML = text;
            container.appendChild(message);
        })
    </script>
```

everything is working as expected - the app sees there is an update, downloads it and installs it.

However, when it is downloading the update, the message appends itself (i know it is the container.appendChild(message) line) however, no matter what i try i cannot replace the message rather than append.

Please let me know what other crucial information i have missed.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to the container each time without clearing the contents first, so you can try clearing the contents first with:

```
container.innerHTML = ''
```

When you then append the child that should be the only element in the container.